# Image Carousel JS Not working for multiple Carousels

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, carousel

Image Carousel JS Not working for multiple Carousels, it works great for one Carousel but when I try to make it work across 1 (or more) it stops functioning, I have tried playing with the code to make it work and no luck so far. Here is where we are at currently:

Carousel JS

```
const slideshow = document.querySelectorAll(".slideshow1, .slideshow2");
const carousel = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel1, .carousel2");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide1, .slide2");
const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

let index = 0,
  firstLast = false,
  intervalId;

const changeSlides = () => {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    index === slides.length - 1 && (firstLast = true);
    index === 0 && (firstLast = false);
    console.log(index);
  }, 2000);
};

changeSlides();

slideshow.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  console.log("Pause");
});

slideshow.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  changeSlides();
  console.log("Play");
});

document.querySelectorAll(".next1, .next2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  index === slides.length - 1 && (index = -1);
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${++index * slideWidth}px)`;
});

document.querySelectorAll(".prev1, .prev2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  index === 0 && (index = slides.length);
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${--index * slideWidth}px)`;
});
```

Carousel HTML:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <div class="slideshow1">
        <a data-target="#" class="control1 prev1">
            <i class='bx bx-left-arrow-circle'></i>
        </a>
        <div class="carousel1">
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="resources/images/Classic Car Collective.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="resources/images/Classic Car Collective.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>  
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="resources/images/Classic Car Collective.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>  
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="resources/images/Classic Car Collective.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>
            <div class="slide1">
                <img src="resources/images/Classic Car Collective.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <a data-target="#" class="control1 next1">
            <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-circle' ></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow2">
        <a data-target="#" class="control2 prev2">
            <i class='bx bx-left-arrow-circle'></i>
        </a>
        <div class="carousel2">
            <div class="slide2">
                <img src="resources/images/Cascade Street Dance.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <img src="resources/images/Cascade Street Dance.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>  
            <div class="slide2">
                <img src="resources/images/Cascade Street Dance.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>  
            <div class="slide2">
                <img src="resources/images/Cascade Street Dance.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <img src="resources/images/Cascade Street Dance.png" alt="Page 1">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <a data-target="#" class="control2 next2">
            <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-circle' ></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

I tried changing the document.querySelector to document.querySelectorAll with multiple arrays but it's not helped, like above shows.

This is the original code I used:

```
const slideshow = document.querySelector(".slideshow");
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

let index = 0,
  firstLast = false,
  intervalId;

const changeSlides = () => {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    index === slides.length - 1 && (firstLast = true);
    index === 0 && (firstLast = false);
    console.log(index);

    firstLast ? index-- : index++;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * slideWidth}px)`;
  }, 2000);
};

changeSlides();

slideshow.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  console.log("Pause");
});

slideshow.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  changeSlides();
  console.log("Play");
});

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  index === slides.length - 1 && (index = -1);
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${++index * slideWidth}px)`;
});

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
  index === 0 && (index = slides.length);
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${--index * slideWidth}px)`;
});
```

Which worked with only 1 carousel.